# IConnectionPoint::Advise method (COM) is slowing down Excel 2016 startup

Tags: com, dde

In my Application I am using the `IConnectionPoint::Advise` method to get a Connection to my `ADODB::ConnectionEvents` implementation.

When `Advise` is called it takes a large amount of time to start up Excel by File Association (e.g. click on a .csv file).

Watching the startup inside [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) showed just some periods of 5 to 15 seconds where nothing seemed to happen.

I made a small example in MSVC to show the exact problem:

```
::CoInitialize(NULL);
IConnectionPointContainer *pCPC = NULL;
IConnectionPoint *pCP = NULL;
ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn;
HRESULT hr;
hr = pConn.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Connection));

hr = pConn->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IConnectionPointContainer), (void **)&pCPC);
hr = pCPC->FindConnectionPoint(__uuidof(ADODB::ConnectionEvents), &pCP);
pCPC->Release();

DWORD dwConnEvt;
IUnknown *pUnk = NULL;
CConnEvent *pConnEvent= NULL;
pConnEvent = new CConnEvent(hEvent);
hr = pConnEvent->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IUnknown), (void **) &pUnk);
hr = pCP->Advise(pUnk, &dwConnEvt);
...
```

And CConnEvent:

```
class CConnEvent : public ADODB::ConnectionEventsVt {
private:
   ULONG m_cRef;
   HANDLE _hEvent;

public:
   CConnEvent(HANDLE &hEvent) : _hEvent(hEvent)
   { m_cRef = 0; };
   ~CConnEvent() {};

   STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppv)
   {
      *ppv = NULL;
      if (riid == __uuidof(IUnknown) || riid == __uuidof(ConnectionEventsVt))
         *ppv = this;

      if (*ppv == NULL)
         return ResultFromScode(E_NOINTERFACE);

      AddRef();
      return NOERROR;
   }
   STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()
   {
      return ++m_cRef;
   }
   STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
   {
      if (0 != --m_cRef)
         return m_cRef;
      delete this;
      return 0;
   }

   STDMETHODIMP raw_InfoMessage( struct ADODB::Error *pError,
      ADODB::EventStatusEnum *adStatus,
   struct ADODB::_Connection *pConnection)
   {
      *adStatus = ADODB::adStatusOK;
      return S_OK;
   }

   STDMETHODIMP raw_BeginTransComplete( LONG TransactionLevel,
   struct ADODB::Error *pError,
      ADODB::EventStatusEnum *adStatus,
   struct ADODB::_Connection *pConnection)
   {
      *adStatus = ADODB::adStatusOK;
      return S_OK;
   }

   STDMETHODIMP raw_CommitTransComplete( struct ADODB::Error *pError,
      ADODB::EventStatusEnum *adStatus,
   struct ADODB::_Connection *pConnection)
   {
      *adStatus = ADODB::adStatusOK;
      return S_OK;
   }

   STDMETHODIMP raw_RollbackTransComplete( struct ADODB::Error *pError,
      ADODB::EventStatusEnum *adStatus,
   struct ADODB::_Connection *pConnection)
   {
      *adStatus = ADODB::adStatusOK;
      return S_OK;
   }

   STDMETHODIMP raw_WillExecute( BSTR *Source,
      ADODB::CursorTypeEnum *CursorType,
      ADODB::LockTypeEnum *LockType,
      long *Options,
      ADODB::EventStatusEnum *adStatus,
   struct ADODB::_Command *pCommand,
   struct ADODB::_Recordset *pRecordset,
   struct ADODB::_Connection *pConnection)
   {
      *adStatus = ADODB::adStatusOK;
      return S_OK;
   }

   STDMETHODIMP raw_ExecuteComplete( LONG RecordsAffected,
   struct ADODB::Error *pError,
      ADODB::EventStatusEnum *adStatus,
   struct ADODB::_Command *pCommand,
   struct ADODB::_Recordset *pRecordset,
   struct ADODB::_Connection *pConnection)
   {
      *adStatus = ADODB::adStatusOK;
      {
         ::SetEvent(_hEvent);
      }
      return S_OK;
   }

   STDMETHODIMP raw_WillConnect( BSTR *ConnectionString,
      BSTR *UserID,
      BSTR *Password,
      long *Options,
      ADODB::EventStatusEnum *adStatus,
   struct ADODB::_Connection *pConnection)
   {
      *adStatus = ADODB::adStatusOK;
      return S_OK;
   }

   STDMETHODIMP raw_ConnectComplete( struct ADODB::Error *pError,
      ADODB::EventStatusEnum *adStatus,
   struct ADODB::_Connection *pConnection)
   {
      *adStatus = ADODB::adStatusOK;
      return S_OK;
   }

   STDMETHODIMP raw_Disconnect( ADODB::EventStatusEnum *adStatus, struct ADODB::_Connection *pConnection)
   {
      *adStatus = ADODB::adStatusOK;
      return S_OK;
   }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Delays that long are environmental problems.  It is too short to suspect a network timeout.  Over-enthusiastic anti-malware is the next suitable candidate, Office programs are popular targets, so disable it and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant The Delay is directly related to the Advise method. It's the same on more then 20 different client machines, no matter which Windows version.

Comment: Well, congratulations, makes it the kind of problem you can pass off to IT staff.  They can figure out what these machines have in common and actually do something to change the machine config.

Comment: The Problem occurs in every different environment. So it seems not like an environmental problem.